# Android: impelment onclick() for button

Tags: android, onclick, adapter

I have this xml-Layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/white" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="200px"> 

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_x="0dp" 
                    android:layout_y="10dp" 
                    android:layout_gravity="left"           
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="Name: " />

                <EditText 
                    android:layout_x = "20px" 
                    android:layout_y = "10px"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="15sp" 
                    android:id="@+id/et_username" android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_width="150px" 
                    android:layout_height="50px" />

                <Button 
                     android:layout_x = "200px" 
                     android:layout_y = "10px" 
                     android:layout_gravity="left"
                     android:textSize="16sp"  
                     android:layout_width="96px" 
                     android:layout_height="50px" 
                     android:background ="@drawable/login"
                     android:id="@+id/btn_login"  
                     android:textColor="@color/white"
                     android:text="next" 
                     android:onClick="onLoginClicked" />

            </AbsoluteLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

java File :

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

...

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   return LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_keyboard, null);
}

public void onLoginClicked(View v) {
   Button button = (Button) v;
   String key = button.getText().toString();
   anotherMethod(key, false);
}
...
}
```

and I use the adapter here:

```
GridView gridview = new GridView(context);
gridview2.setAdapter(new KeyboardAdapter(1, context));
```

can anybody tell me, why do I get the following error when I click the button?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onLoginClicked(View) in the activity class MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
```

Comment: Your onLoginClicked(View v) method is in your ButtonAdapter class instead of your MainActivity?

Comment: Are you sure, your `onLoginClicked` method is in the MainActivity class, and not in your `ButtonAdapter` - it is looked for in the MainActivity.

Comment: I have the 'ButtonAdapter' inorder not to have everything in my Activity.

Answer (score 3):

This happening because you have the following in your xml:

```
  <Button 
                 android:layout_x = "200px" 
                 android:layout_y = "10px" 
                 android:layout_gravity="left"
                 android:textSize="16sp"  
                 android:layout_width="96px" 
                 android:layout_height="50px" 
                 android:background ="@drawable/login"
                 android:id="@+id/btn_login"  
                 android:textColor="@color/white"
                 android:text="next" 
                 android:onClick="onLoginClicked" />
```

The last line means that when this button is clicked, a method will be invoked. This method is named "onLoginClicked", it should be public and have a parameter of type `View` and be defined in the Activity class.

So, go to your activity and write something like:

```
public void onLoginClicked(View v) {
    //toast, log, open activity, etc
}
```

Comment: How do you choose WHICH activity class to look in? I'm trying to implement fragments and I have buttons on those fragments that need their own onclick functions but I don't want to cram everything into one main activity. So I've partitioned the code for the onclick for that fragment into that fragment's definition file but Android keeps searching for my function in my main activity.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to make the code more complex. 
Just try to do this :

```
Button b=(Button)findViewId(R.id.btn_login);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                //perform your action here            
            });
```

Comment: I think I can't, because my Button is not in my Activity class!

Comment: you can use **viewHolder()** method to receive the button runtime from any XML.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. should I define all the buttons I have in my viewholder?

Comment: you can, no problem in that and used only that one in which you want add listener and perform some action.

Comment: I've try that but it doesn't look good to have all the 60 Buttons in the holder. I mean I have the xml-Layout in order not to make Buttons programmatically!  As I said there are more than one Button in my xml-Layout. Is that the only way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the onClick parameter from your layout XML and handle the click with a listener. Add this code to your onCreate() method in your activity:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                String key = button.getText().toString();
                   anotherMethod(key, false);               
            });
```

Comment: I think I can't, because my Button is not in my Activity class! It's a child in a gridlayout which is the child of a viewflipper and I have many of this Buttons.